# SVG Mask CSS transform applied in Chrome but not in Firefox or Edge

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg, microsoft-edge

I have a picture that is masked by a series of paths, in this form:

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask">
      <g style="transform: ...snip...">
        <g style="transform: ...snip...">
          <path d="...snip..."></path>
        </g>
        <g style="transform: ...snip...">
           <path d="...snip..."></path>
        </g>
        ...more paths nested w/<g> elements...
      </g>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <foreignObject mask="url(#mask)">
    <img></img>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

This picture correctly renders in Google Chrome as masked by the paths defined in the mask element.

In Firefox and Microsoft Edge (untested in other browsers), the image is also masked by the paths defined in the mask element. However, the `transform:` calls defined in the `style` attributes of the elements are apparently not called, and as such the paths appear incorrectly. Why would this happen?

Comment: It happens because it's not yet implemented in Firefox. Use transform attributes rather than styles if you want this to work.